# Pynput Listener is not calling on_press function

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard-events, keylistener, pynput

I'm using `pynput.keyboard.Listener` to listen for keyboard input. The function that is passed to its `on_press` or `on_release` arguments is never called after starting the Listener thread although the thread is running (checked with its `ìs_alive()` method).

A minimal example as it is also given by the pynput documentation is (for non-blocking operation):

```
import pynput.keyboard as kb

def say(key):
    print(key)

lis=kb.Listener(on_press=say, on_release=say)
lis.start()

while True:
    pass
```

the function `say` is never called, neither on pressing or releasing any key.
`lis.is_alive()` returns `True` after starting it.
No Error is shown or Exception raised.
Running the Listener blocking with `lis.join()` doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by switching from Wayland to X11 on the Ubuntu 22.04 machine.

Apparently no key presses were ever registered by the `Listener` while using Wayland.